# Nhibernate -doing things in the constructor

Tags: c#, nhibernate, constructor

I have a feeling that me asking this question may suggest that my design needs some refactoring, but here goes..

NHibernate constructs classes using a empty no argument constructor and then sets the properties. What if I wanted to do some logic after the object is constructed and properties are instantiated?  Is there a way I can specifcy a method to run when everything has been created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use PostLoadEventListeners.
Google "nhibernate event listeners"